# Grey line on the left of rows

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have div rows inside div containers and all of them show a weird grey line, only on the left border, I can't figure out why.

I assume it's not a CSS problem, I tried removing it but the grey line persists.
I'm using Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta.2.

Here is a print of the site with the code snippet:
http://prntscr.com/ob28hj

Comment: can you please give your code here. its really tough to figure it out without seeing it

Comment: mock up your code in https://codepen.io/pen/ and we can have a look. But like Irin mentioned, its tough from a screen shot. GL

Comment: Nevermind, I'm sorry, I figured it out. I'm using a e-commerce plataform and seems like the problem is with one of the tags they use by default, I guess its some conflict with Bootstrap 4, since they use Bootstrap 3 on the default layout.